# Changing Aspect Ratio of the video on Button Click using Surface View like MX player

Tags: android, surfaceview, aspect-ratio, scaletype

I am making a video player android application like MX player. what i want to do is same like in MX player.For example:If the user clicks on the **aspect ratio** button it should set the video size to **100%**. if the user again clicks the button it should set (aspect ratio or scale type  to be **crop**.on next click it should set to **stretch**. again it should set it to **fit to screen** etc.

---

i have developed other logic of the player except this button. i will handle the clicks logic on the aspect ratio button too.

---

just tell me what code i will need to write to **change the video size not the surface view size** when the user selects the button.

---

**Note:** I am not using video view at all. i am assigning surface view a media player through surface holder. and **by default** my video plays in full screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have **done** it finally after some research. if anyone is looking for an answer then it is here for you. it is **not** the **correct size** though but it is for an example. the **set Text** is **not** according to the **width** and **height** but it is **just to explain** you the **functionality**

---

you can **get** the **screen width** and **height** and **+/-** the amount you want to **increase** or **decrease** in **width** and **height** whatever you want.

---

above your activity, after **imports** you write this to **initialize**:

```
android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp;
```

This piece of code will get the device width and height.

```
  public void getDeviceWidthAndHeight(){
    lp = surfaceView.getLayoutParams();
    screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    screenHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
}
```

And this piece of code will set the height and width you give to it.

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    int id=v.getId();
    if (id==R.id.resize_video){
        if (clickCount==0){
            getDeviceWidthAndHeight();
            lp.width = screenWidth-50;
            lp.height = screenHeight-50;
            surfaceView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            resizeVideo.setText("100%");
            clickCount=1;
        }
    else if (clickCount==1){
            getDeviceWidthAndHeight();
            lp.width = screenWidth-300;
            lp.height = screenHeight-100;
            surfaceView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            resizeVideo.setText("Full Screen");
            clickCount=2;
    }
    else if(clickCount==2){
            getDeviceWidthAndHeight();
            lp.width =screenWidth;
            lp.height = screenHeight;
            surfaceView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            resizeVideo.setText("100%");
            clickCount=3;
        }
        else if(clickCount==3){
            getDeviceWidthAndHeight();
            lp.width =screenWidth;
            lp.height = screenHeight-500;
            surfaceView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            resizeVideo.setText("Fit to Screen");
            clickCount=0;
        }
    }

}
```